# isset function does not get SESSION variable

Tags: php, isset

I have a problem with a script.
In this php file I have a script that has to verify if 2 variables are equal:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) )
{   
   if(isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {
        $vkey = $_SESSION["vkey"];
        $code = $_POST["code"];

        if($vkey == $code){ 
            echo 'Ti-ai verificat emailul.';
        }else{
            echo 'ERROR2';
        }
    } else {
       echo 'ERROR3';
    }
} else { 
    header("location: ../index.php?error=wtf");
}
?>
```

After running this on this form:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; 
print_r($_SESSION)?>
<div class="container mt-3"><div class="card"><div class="card-header text-center">
User Account Activation by Email Verification</div>
<div class="card-body">
<form method="post" action="includes/codeeq.php">
<label for="fname">Insert the code received in the email</label><br>
<input type="text" id="code" name="code"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

I get redirected to index.php?error=wtf, so my guess is that the script is ignoring the first if where isset session is.
Also, the vkey in the session is not NULL.
this is the print_r output
[print_r output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnKLE.png)

Comment: You are missing session_start() as first call of every script.

Comment: session_start() is in header.php, the session is already started. also, I provided the print_r($_SESSION) above, so its clearly that the session is working

Comment: session_start() is in header.php, but it's not in `codeeq.php`!

Comment: Ok, I did not know that you need to start the session 2 times, in my head, if its started you dont need to start it again.

Comment: You only need to call session_start() once per request. You have started the session in your header.php, which is the form. When you submit the form, it will make a _new_ request from the client to `includes/codeeq.php` (which is what you put in the forms `action`-attribute). Every request from the client to PHP starts your application from scratch. Since that will be a new request, you need to start the session there before you can use the `$_SESSION`-variable.